# How do I get the Title for a person?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GroupName" | Select Name,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName,Title
```

I get everything except the job title of the person. I'd also like to get the description.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much what the guy above said, but a different method.

Basically the command has a set of default properties that it pulls, anything beyond that you have to specify

```
Import-Module -Name "ActiveDirectory"    
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "GroupName" | Get-ADUser -Properties "Title" | Select-Object -Property ("Name", "Title")
```